# SQL - search through phrase with no spaces

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

How would You manage to search if phrase contains exact words in MySQL ?

f.e. if there is a column `phrase` with phrase: 
    *'Hello my name is Jack'* 
and I would like to search if it contains words: 'name' and 'Jack' - it is quiet simple:

```
SELECT `phrase` FROM column WHERE `phrase` RLIKE '[[:<:]]name[[:>:]]' 
AND `phrase` RLIKE '[[:<:]]Jack[[:>:]]'
```

But how would You manage to do that if phrase would be like:
    *'HelloMyNameIsJack'* ?? 
(without spaces)

EDIT: I cant use 'LIKE' cause if there would be another phrase: *'HelloMyXyznamexyzIsJack'* - it would find me whole phrase - which I dont want to - I just want to find words

EDIT 2: it's hard to explain but let me try that way: I want to find a phrase which contains given words BUT as a words - if I give words 'name' and 'Jack' - I DONT want to find f.e. 'HelloMyNamesIsJacky' - the problem is how to let the sql know which of 'HelloMyNamesIsJacky' are words (since there are no spaces between them)

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can use `like`. No need of a regex here

Comment: @up: how ?Remember, that I'm asking about example without spaces

Comment: Do you want the words in order as well? As in, what about "Jack is my name."?

Comment: @Tim Lehner:No need to have words in order. I'm just simply looking for a way to search for match with exact words, but in a case where phrase has no spaces

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your existing regex, then. It's hard to tell what you are looking for. You might try providing a truth table with enough examples of pass and fail as to be unambiguous.

Comment: As it is, it looks like you want to put spaces before all uppercase characters, then run your regex search.

Comment: @Tim Lehner: yep - that's what I want (or try) to do! I want to search each phrase if it contains given words (f.e. 'name' and 'jack) - but I dont want to find phrases with 'jacky' or 'names' - I want exact word - and the problem is that my data is stored in -without space- strings. And thats the problem - how to let the code see phrase f.e. ''HelloMyNameIsJack'' as a ''Hello My Name Is Jack'

Comment: You must first define "word".  Then test that the definition works correctly for your examples.  After that, we may be able to help you with a regexp or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Given your edits, it sounds like this would work using `concat` with `like`:

```
select phrase
from yourtable
where concat(' ',phrase,' ') like '% name %' and 
      concat(' ',phrase,' ') like '% Jack %'
```

Note -- this could still fail if your sentence ends in a period.  You'd have to code for such a case...

Comment: @user6615224 -- you need to do a better job defining your requirements and explaining why it doesn't work versus just saying it doesn't work.  Obviously a lot of us are confused... this answer will match 'Hello my name is jack' but not match 'Hellomynameisjack'...

Comment: Yeah, I;m trying - please take a look at the Edit and Edit2 in main post

Comment: @user6615224 -- You don't have spaces in your existing data? If not, there's no way you can pass in `jack` and not match `jacky` as well... these are some odd requirements -- why on earth would the data be stored that way?  if you're trying to get `sql` to break apart a string with no spaces into potential words, you aren't going to have much luck.

Comment: that's exactly what I have - data stored in strings without spaces.... Only capital letters in the first letter of each word

Answer (score 1):

To find words like your examples, You might try prepending your uppercase letters with spaces, and then running your existing regex. This is not the same as parsing English words out of your data, however, which would be fraught with technical challenges. It might work as a quick hack for you, though.

Based on your examples, I've done a few letters here to give you an idea (but you would want to add A, B, C...):

```
select Phrase
from MyTable
where replace(replace(replace(Phrase, 'I', ' I'), 'J', ' J'), 'N', ' N') rlike '[[:<:]]name[[:>:]]'
  and replace(replace(replace(Phrase, 'I', ' I'), 'J', ' J'), 'N', ' N') rlike '[[:<:]]Jack[[:>:]]'
```

Given data like:

```
'Hello my name is Jack'
'HelloMyNameIsJack'
'HelloMyXyznamexyzIsJack'
'HelloMyNamesIsJacky'
'HelloMyNameIsJacky'
'HelloJackIsMyName'
```

Your results would be:

```
'Hello my name is Jack'
'HelloMyNameIsJack'
'HelloJackIsMyName'
```

Comment: wow - thats a nice way! But the prolbem is that the data is stored in thousands or even more records....

Comment: @user6615224 I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying the performance is unacceptable?

Comment: Sadly there are thousands of records so I dont think it would work. And - why even this example does not work in my MySql database ? It's throwing me an arror

Comment: @user6615224 I highly doubt the computer will balk at the tedium.

Comment: it's working now, but as I said - there are thousands of records so it probably wont work. I just needed an answer - is there a way, or is it senseless, so thx for your confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you still use `LIKE` operator

```
SELECT `phrase` 
FROM `column`
WHERE `phrase` LIKE '%name%' 
AND `phrase` LIKE '%Jack'
```

Looks like you rather should be going for [`Full-Text Search`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) in that case

Comment: nope, cause if there will be phrase f.e. 'HelloMyXyznamexx' - it would find whole word - which I dont want to

Comment: @user6615224, No it will not due to the `and` condition. I am trying to match both `name` and `Jack` in the same string.

Comment: U dont understand - read edit